# How use @property decorator syntax in litElement when there are properties from the redux

Tags: typescript, vaadin, decorator, web-component, lit-element

when we use constructor assign @property decoratort looks like

```
@property ({type: String}) name = 'Luis';
```

and its work fine
but when I use redux and therefore _stateChanged for it I try use

```
@property ({type: String}) name
```

without name value because value defines in _stateChanged function
so how make it works together

I find a lot of example where people use this decorator like this

```
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
 

     @property({type: String}) propertyName = "name"
```

and it works instead constructor definition, but in my case I have
`_stateChanged function` and when I write code like this, it dont work like it should be, please give me example usage this decorators with `_stateChanged(redux)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using the regular `@property` regardless of whether the value is set from the outside or internally from e.g. Redux. The type information is only there to let LitElement populate the property value based on an attribute but it's ignored as long as attribute with the same name is set.

You can also use `@internalProperty` that doesn't require you to define type and also doesn't reflect the property to an attribute with the same name.

Comment: thanks, but I dont understand how keep using @property
my page dont update when I declare like this

Comment: @property ({type: String}) name
 _stateChanged(state) {
        this.name = state.redux.name
    }

Comment: how I need make litElement know that name is changed in _stateChanged

Comment: please write some examle how describe data in _stateChanged with @property decorator

Comment: Nothing should be needed unless there's some bug in parts of the code that isn't shown. What `@property` does is that it makes LitElement listen to changes to the value to that property, regardless of how that value is changed. LitElement doesn't need to know that `_stateChanged` is the function that actually updates the value - all it cares about is that the value is changed.

Comment: Or is your question actually about how to make `_stateChanged` run when something changes in Redux?

Comment: Yes I wwanna that my data update when redux has been changed, so in past I just describe data in   static get properties() { but how describe it with decorator

Comment: why litElement stop listen my changes when I use decorators instead tatic get properties()  to describe data that can be changed

Comment: Maybe  I need use typescript files for this syntax?

Comment: I notice that property decorator dont work at all and dont watch changes, but customElement decortor is ok, what can be cause of this